# Codenameone - Transparency or Style issue on form

Tags: codenameone

Buttons and Labels from another form will display on the current form. Please see the attached screenshot. This is even happening on Simulator, Android and Apple devices.

I'm using one form style in theme.res and all the forms in the application will extend that form.

If this is a problem due to Transparency setting for form or Buttons, please provide an example.

[image]
Using following code for classes:

```
public class AppointmentsForm extends BaseForm
public class BaseForm extends Form
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Form's can have any transparency or translucency so if the form UIID was changed in any way you need to make sure that background transparency is still explicitly defined to 255.

Comment: Yes Shai. I did that. Still I'm having this issue on some forms. Please advise is there something else I'm missing here. Do I have to set the UIID for the form in the code? I'm using the code like : public class AppointmentsForm extends BaseForm

Comment: I have added description for the ticket with code and screenshot. Please advise.

Comment: Shai, Do you think setting the form this.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(255) in the affected form will fix the issue? I still don't understand the reason behind appearance of button from another form to this form. Making Transparency(255) will make any difference. Please advise.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly call that in code. Unless you invoked `setUIID` in the form it should be good. Can you extract a test case that reproduces the issue?